# What is wrong with the following api call to logout user?

Tags: 8, users

When i call drupal rest api to logout with following parameters

```
axios.post('http://my-lando-app.lndo.site/user/logout?_format=json', {
    'csrf_token':  this.state.csrf_token,
    'logout_token' : this.state.logout_token,
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
})
```

I get response

```
{"message":"\u0027csrf_token\u0027 URL query argument is missing."}
```

what is wrong with my request?

Comment: Did you solve or found out what it was in the end? Got the same issue with `react`. Same code on `react-native` works.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this error with angularjs(D8.5). This code works for me.

```
getUserLogout(logoutToken,csrfToken) {
  // post logout
  return this.http.get(
    'http://localhost:8082/d8/api/user/logout?_format=json&token='+logoutToken,
    {
      headers:
      {
        'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken
      },
      withCredentials: true
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's mentioning a URL query argument, that seems to indicate that the csrf_token should be appended to the URL as a GET variable, rather than including it in your POST data. Or maybe the entire request is supposed to be GET instead of POST.

Comment: when i make entire get request i get following error "{"message":"The \u0022user\u0022 parameter was not converted for the path \u0022\/user\/{user}\u0022 (route name: \u0022rest.entity.user.GET\u0022)"}"

Answer (score 0):

It’s trying to load a user with an ID of ‘logout’ it would seem. I haven’t worked with the API much - maybe the endpoint is different for logging out. Or more likely I’m thinking it’s probably supposed to be a GET or some other type of request other than POST.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://www.drupal.org/node/2720655#comment-11951796

Answer (score 0):

This works on Drupal 8.5.1:

```
this.serverRequest = axios.get('/user/logout', '', {headers: {
  'X-CSRF-Token': localStorage.getItem('csrf_token')}
});
```

Also works without the csrf_token header. I did read a call to require a token for logout but I'm not sure if it's the csrf_token or the logout_token.

I'm interesed to heard whether this works for you, or did you find another way?

Comment: I am getting 403 error with above i tried all the combination

Answer (score 0):

It's probably Drupal cannot read the `token` parameter in the URL. Or can not read the credentials (Cookie for example).

Make sure the POST request that you are making to the /user/logout contain the Cookie header. Or if you are using the `HttpHeaders` make sure to set the `withCredentials: true`.

The URL of this resource is: `user/logout?_format=json&token=TOKEN_HERE`

No need to post something in the body. POST nothing just pass the two parameters in the URL `_format=json&token=TOKEN_HERE`

NOTE: The user should be anonymous in order to have a successful POST to this service. Or you have to clear your browser/client sessions and cookie and try again.